# How to SUM() fields in a pivoted table

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a MySQL table sort of like this

```
Table 'club_funds'
| Income    | Label                   | Amount  |
+-----------+-------------------------+---------+
| 1         | Membership fees         |    1000 |
| 0         | Gathering party costs   |     500 |
| 1         | Garage sale profit      |     250 |
```

which I managed to turn into this

```
| Label                   | Income | Expense |
+-------------------------+--------+---------+
| Membership fees         |   1000 |         |
| Gathering party costs   |        |     500 |
| Garage sale profit      |    250 |         |
```

using this query

```
SELECT Label,
IF (income = 1, amount, null) AS `Income`,
IF (income = 0, amount, null) AS `Expense`
FROM club_funds
```

Now, I want to add a total to the bottom row.

```
| Label                   | Income | Expense |
+-------------------------+--------+---------+
| Membership fees         |   1000 |         |
| Gathering party costs   |        |     500 |
| Garage sale profit      |    250 |         |
| Total                   |   1250 |     500 |
```

I've been reading about adding a total row to the bottom of a table, but it involves `ROLLUP` which is a modifier for `GROUP BY`. As you can see above, I do not use `GROUP BY` for this so I can't use `ROLLUP` (or can I?).

So, I'm thinking of adding this at the end of the query

```
UNION SELECT 'Total', SUM(Income), SUM(Expense)
```

but I got this error

```
Unknown column 'Income' in 'field list'
```

Any way I can make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROLLUP` if you add a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Label, 'Total') AS Label,
       SUM(IF (income = 1, amount, null)) AS `Income`,
       SUM(IF (income = 0, amount, null)) AS `Expense`
FROM club_funds
GROUP BY Label WITH ROLLUP
```

In MySQL you can also simplify your query a bit like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Label, 'Total'),
       SUM((income = 1)*amount) AS `Income`,
       SUM((income = 0)*amount) AS `Expense`
FROM club_funds
GROUP BY Label WITH ROLLUP
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4710e/2)

Answer (score 3):

I think that its either because you are missing a from in the second select or because you are tring to select from the table it self, which doesn't have columns income and expense yet, because other that , the query is fine.. so try:

```
SELECT Label,
IF (income = 1, amount, null) AS `Income`,
IF (income = 0, amount, null) AS `Expense`
FROM club_funds
UNION
(SELECT 'Total' as `label`,
       sum(case when income = 1 then amount else 0) as `Income`,
       sum(case when income = 0 then amount else 0) as `Expense`
FROM club_funds)
```